# Shouldn't floating an inline element create three block level elements?

Tags: html, css

Here's my doubt. If I float an inline element, since it's display is automatically set to block, and since siblings of block level elements have to be themselves block level elements(anonymous ones if they must), shouldn't in the example below, the first and second anonymous blocks be placed on separate lines as block level elements do by default?

```
<p>
   This will be the first anonymous block, <span style="float: left;">this will 
   be the span</span>, and this will be the second anonymous block.
</p>
```

See my demo: http://tinkerbin.com/5niDbThT

Notice that when I directly set the display to block on the span of the second paragraph, three different block level elements are created - just as I imagined it would happen when floating.

My guess is that floating is simply an exception that doesn't trigger the effect. But you tell me ;). Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the first example is correct behavior.  The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level) says that "When an inline box contains an **in-flow** block-level box, the inline box (...) [is] broken around the block-level box...".  Floated boxes are not in-flow.  Later on that page, there's actually an [example](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#comp-float) that's very similar to yours, which seems to reinforce that it's "by design".  That doesn't quite explain why adding `display:block` changes anything, though (the box is still out of flow, right?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floats take the object out of the document flow which is why it shows up as it does.

Inline-block: "The element is placed as an inline element (on the same line as adjacent content), but it behaves as a block element"

You can also "clear" dom elements which pushes the element past the floated object. Most commonly used in a layout with a main area and a right/left column side by side.

Comment: Yes. Makes sense. It's in the definition of a float - simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I thought about your question and the implications for a while and this is the conclusion I've come to:

So according to the W3 CSS spec,  http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#floats, "Content flows down the right side of a left-floated box and down the left side of a right-floated box." So what the first example span in your tinkerbin is doing is perfectly normal; it's what is supposed to happen when a floated element comes in contact with any content. Actually in your tinkerbin you didn't set the span with display:block as float:left, so it just created a scenario where the other elements have to be treated as block-level, as you mentioned.

If you do apply float:left to span-2, you get the same result as span-1.

I edited your tinkerbin and put in a div structure: http://tinkerbin.com/NoOqLU4O which uncovers additional weirdness. It seems to treat text before the div as a block but text after it as content. Who knows?

Bottom line I think that you're right, floating is an exception that doesn't trigger the effect because it's hard to put a finger on what exactly is "content that should wrap to the float" when your float itself is content..

Comment: In the third case, the one you created, it seems that the siblings recognize the div's default block display prior to the floating. So, when you float it, only the preceding sibling will have it's content flowing to the right of the div. But a lot of other weird things are happening. I tried, for example, adding a background-color to the containing p element, set the overflow to hidden to contain the float, but it ends up applying only to the first anonymous block - can't figure it out. Probably something in the specs I haven't read yet.

Comment: But yeah, we're adding a div inside a p - that's bad html - and probably the reason why it messes things up. Thanks for your answer!